# Having trouble displaying custom post meta via a short code in a WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, meta

I've created a plugin that sets up a custom post type ('Programmes'), taxonomy and a short code to display the custom posts. I'm trying to display a custom post meta field (Broadcast Date) via the shortcode. These are the methods I've tried so far:

This is the method I'd have preferred as it allows me to use it for multiple meta values:

```
if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <div class="schedule-container">
        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        $programmeImage = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID, 'thumbnail') );           
        $programmeMeta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_meta_content',TRUE);
        ?>
        <div id="programme-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?> style="background-image: url( <?php echo $programmeImage ?> )">
            <div class="schedule-titlebar">
                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <p><?php echo $programmeMeta['broadcast-date'] ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </ul>
}
```

But that didn't work so I tried this instead:

```
if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <div class="schedule-container">
        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        $programmeImage = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID, 'thumbnail') );           
        $programmeBroadcastDate = get_post_meta($post->ID,'broadcast-date',TRUE);
        ?>
        <div id="programme-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?> style="background-image: url( <?php echo $programmeImage ?> )">
            <div class="schedule-titlebar">
                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <p><?php echo $programmeBroadcastDate ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </ul>
}
```

and that doesn't work either!

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: what is the meta key, `_meta_content` or `broadcast-date`?

Comment: It's `broadcast-date`. I was under the impression that if I used `_meta_content` I could use then use $programmeMeta to call any piece of meta data by using it like I have in my first example: `$programmeMeta['broadcast-date']`

That was based on this example (although there's a typo in his code): https://wordpress.org/support/topic/using-shortcodes-to-display-post-meta-data-within-a-page